# How to play videos from the "CastVideos-android sample app" on mobile, when no wifi/chromecast to display them on TV?

Tags: android, video, chromecast, google-cast

I have installed the CastVideos-android sample app as described in the official site [official cast Android site](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cast-videos-android/#2) and using the [code available in the referenced repository](https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-android) (Thanks to @entertailion).

The sample works perfectly when casting the videos to chromecast via wifi.

[image]

However, I would also need the mobile app to **display videos on the mobile** when using it out-of-home **via 3G** without casting to TV. **This feature was available in previous versions**. It does not work since the project was moved to Android Studio: When clicking on the item, the waiting icon appears, the video is not displayed in the mobile, and after some seconds you are redirected to the home playlist.

Here is the log from logcat:

```
 com.google.sample.cast.refplayer D/dalvikvm: get native done
 com.google.sample.cast.refplayer I/dalvikvm:     at android.media.MediaPlayer.updateProxyConfig(Native Method)
 com.google.sample.cast.refplayer I/dalvikvm:     at android.media.MediaPlayer.handleProxyBroadcast(MediaPlayer.java:3092)
 com.google.sample.cast.refplayer I/dalvikvm:     at android.media.MediaPlayer.setupProxyListener(MediaPlayer.java:3067)
 com.google.sample.cast.refplayer I/dalvikvm:     at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:935)
 com.google.sample.cast.refplayer I/dalvikvm:     at android.widget.VideoView.openVideo(VideoView.java:419)
 com.google.sample.cast.refplayer I/dalvikvm:     at android.widget.VideoView$7.surfaceCreated(VideoView.java:719)
 com.google.sample.cast.refplayer I/dalvikvm:     at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:662)
 com.google.sample.cast.refplayer I/dalvikvm:     at android.view.SurfaceView.setVisibility(SurfaceView.java:275)
 com.google.sample.cast.refplayer I/dalvikvm:     at com.google.sample.cast.refplayer.mediaplayer.LocalPlayerActivity.setCoverArtStatus(LocalPlayerActivity.java:373)
 com.google.sample.cast.refplayer I/dalvikvm:     at com.google.sample.cast.refplayer.mediaplayer.LocalPlayerActivity.updatePlaybackLocation(LocalPlayerActivity.java:248)
 com.google.sample.cast.refplayer I/dalvikvm:     at com.google.sample.cast.refplayer.mediaplayer.LocalPlayerActivity.togglePlayback(LocalPlayerActivity.java:314)
 com.google.sample.cast.refplayer I/dalvikvm:     at com.google.sample.cast.refplayer.mediaplayer.LocalPlayerActivity.access$2300(LocalPlayerActivity.java:78)
 com.google.sample.cast.refplayer I/dalvikvm:     at com.google.sample.cast.refplayer.mediaplayer.LocalPlayerActivity$9.onClick(LocalPlayerActivity.java:776)
 com.google.sample.cast.refplayer I/dalvikvm:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4463)
 com.google.sample.cast.refplayer I/dalvikvm:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18770)
 com.google.sample.cast.refplayer I/dalvikvm:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
 com.google.sample.cast.refplayer I/dalvikvm:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
 com.google.sample.cast.refplayer I/dalvikvm:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
 com.google.sample.cast.refplayer I/dalvikvm:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5333)
 com.google.sample.cast.refplayer I/dalvikvm:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 com.google.sample.cast.refplayer I/dalvikvm:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
 com.google.sample.cast.refplayer I/dalvikvm:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
 com.google.sample.cast.refplayer I/dalvikvm:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
 com.google.sample.cast.refplayer I/dalvikvm:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 com.google.sample.cast.refplayer E/dalvikvm: VM aborting
04-19 10:23:33.905 4902-4902/com.google.sample.cast.refplayer A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) at 0x00001326 (code=-6), thread 4902 (.cast.refplayer)

...

com.google.sample.cast.refplayer D/skia: jpeg_decoder mode 1, config 6, w 479, h 270, sample 1, bsLength 5a96!!
com.google.sample.cast.refplayer D/ViewGroup: addInArray been called, this = android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView{41d2c0f8 VFED.V.. .F....ID 0,0-480,741 #7f0f00c6 app:id/list}call stack =
        java.lang.Throwable: addInArray
            at android.view.ViewGroup.addInArray(ViewGroup.java:3791)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3745)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3569)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3514)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$5.addView(RecyclerView.java:611)
            at android.support.v7.widget.ChildHelper.addView(ChildHelper.java:107)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.addViewInt(RecyclerView.java:6728)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.addView(RecyclerView.java:6686)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.addView(RecyclerView.java:6674)
            at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1404)
            at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1353)
            at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:574)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3028)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:2906)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3283)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15125)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4867)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1160)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15125)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4867)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1160)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15125)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4867)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:515)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:450)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15125)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4867)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1888)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1742)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1651)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15125)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4867)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:515)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:450)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15125)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4867)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1888)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1742)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1651)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15125)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4867)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:515)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:450)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15125)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4867)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2317)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2023)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1189)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6223)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:788)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:591)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:560)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:774)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5333)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote
```

Any suggestions or ideas?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, Chromecast-enabled applications have an overall design principle wherein casting relies on the coordination between two or more screens; the sender UI and the receiver UI — they must work together. You may want to check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/ux_guidelines) for more information or [send feedback](https://support.google.com/cast-developer/answer/6154131?hl=en&ref_topic=3547309) to the Google Cast Team if you want to suggest a new feature.

Answer (score 0):

There is no requirement to have WiFi even for casting. So to answer your question first: you can play content locally as long as you have internet access, whether it is through WiFi or data connectivity. In fact I just tried the latest version of the CastVideos-android to make sure we haven't broken anything there and it worked just fine with no WiFi.

In addition, you don't even need to have WiFi to be able to successfully cast to a cast device; as long as Guest Mode is turned on for the cast device, you can stay on data connectivity and find and cast to such a cast device.

If you are running into an issue with local playback when WiFi is turned off, I suggest you first give the CastVideos-android app a try and then see what you are doing differently in your app that is failing if there is no WiFi connectivity.